# using Visual C++ 2010.. How do I change the value of a progressbar from outside the Form1 class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, progress

using Visual C++ 2010.. I'm trying to use a progress bar, and change the value from outside the Form1 class, and in another question from:

https://ccplz.net/threads/windows-form-problem.38558/

Nazgul1444 says that:

```
You should not make the progressbar public. Use a Set function.

SetProgressBar(int i);
```

But... how do I do that exactly?

tried this:

```
public: static void SetProgressBar(int i) {
    this->progressBar1->Value = i;
}
```

but then it says can't use "this" inside a static function

Also, is this the correct way to call from outside?:

```
Form1::SetProgressBar(x);
```

---

is there anyway to do something like this to have only one instance of the form?:

```
Form1 FMain;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
// Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

// Create the main window and run it
FMain = gcnew Form1();
Application::Run(FMain);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't need to be a static function.  Define it as non-static, and call it through an instance of the form.

```
SomeProc()
{
    Form1 f1 = ...

    ...

    f1.SetProgressBar(n);
}
```

In this (extremely short) snippet, `f1` is an instance of your `Form1` class.

Comment: but doesn't creating another instance create another window?  can I do something like I added above?

Comment: Substitute `FMain` for `f1`.  As `FMain` in your snippet is a 'global' variable, that can be used as your instance variable, your instance of the form.  So in any procedure in that source file, you should be able to call `FMain.SetProgressBar(n)`, assuming that `SetProgressBar` is non-static.

Comment: error C3145: 'FMain' : global or static variable may not have managed type 'Fourth::Form1' ...tried using public and private but are those just for classes?

Comment: Change the declaration of the form variable to be a pointer: `Form1 * FMain;`.  That probably wont fix everything, but it should get you one step closer.  I don't have a c++ compiler handy for testing, sorry, but maybe someone else will step up and help you through the next bit.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to bail, but some things to check:  Ensure the Form1 class is public, ensure that the Form1.h file (or equivalent) is included.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.